# Make a container with an image to the left and a title paragraph to the right in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a container image-text style for my landing page, but after hours of research I couldn't find any useful example for my problems which seems pretty basic.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7WbT.png)

Is there a name for this type of container/header to look for them? I would love if someone could write a simple example to replicate it, because all of my solutions are not very elegant mainly because I am new to pure CSS (I'm being asked to not use any CSS libraries) I want my landing page to have multiple rows of this containers as this web page (without the animations of course) [Overflow Webpage](https://overflow.io/)

So far I have tried something like this

HTML

```
<div class="header_2">
    <article>
        <h1>Multiples Odontólogos en todo Santiago</h1>
        <p>If your knees aren't green by the end of the day, you ought to seriously re-examine your life.</p>
        <a href="/pacientes">Únete ></a>
      </article>
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="<%= assetPath('Land1.svg') %>" alt="Odontólogos por todo Santiago">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header_2 {
  padding: 10vh 15vw;
  background: #def2f1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #17252a;
} 

.header_2 img {
  max-height: 30%;  
  max-width: 30%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header_2 article{
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 50vw;
}

.header_2 h1 {
  font-family: 'Kanit';
  color: #17252a;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
}

.header_2 p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #17252a;
  font-size: 1vw;

}

.header_2 a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #3aafa9;
  font-size: 1vw;

}
```

With these results:
[My Actual Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeZvl.png)
I can't set the image and text in the same line and my div is huge. Which is the most elegant and simple solution fr this type of style?

Comment: I think you can use flexbox, you can find a lot of tutorials online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
|HTML|
<div class="header_2">
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-6">
        <img src="<%= assetPath('Land1.svg') %>" alt="Odontólogos por todo Santiago">
    </div>
    <article class="box-6">
        <h1>Multiples Odontólogos en todo Santiago</h1>
        <p>If your knees aren't green by the end of the day, you ought to seriously re-examine your life.</p>
        <a href="/pacientes">Únete ></a>
    </article>
</div>
```

```
|CSS|
        .header_2 {
        padding: 10vh 15vw;
        background: #def2f1;
        color: #17252a;
        margin:0;
    }
    .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .box-6{
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

Using flex:
Add this code to '.header_2' and adjust your padding-right on .header_2 article:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
```

Using inline-block:
Add this code to '.header_2 article' and adjust the padding-right you have on this class:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Using float:
With this option it won't be aligned vertically so depends on what you want.
Add this code to '.header_2 article' and adjust the padding-right you have on this class:

```
float: left;
```